# Can I have one folder with many HTML files?

Tags: php, html, directory

I confess, I am not even really a programmer: I am an illustrator trying to launch a webcomic I've been working on with just some basic HTML, CSS, and JS. The site would include a main page with a new image and comments section for every update, an about page, and an archive to access all previous pages (a la xkcd or Gunnerkrigg Court, for example). What I tried to do at first was create a separate HTML doc for each page of my comic. I have found that most actual webcomics use some form of PHP, which I would love to learn, but may not have time for right now as I'm currently studying art, not coding. My question is (I suspect I know the answer but want to check): Can I just put each page on its own HTML file, or will that make my site horribly slow and janky? How many different pages can I put in my root folder and not kill my site?

The site will probably have about 25 pages by the time I'm in a position to start learning PHP or other dynamic content techniques.

Comment: Yes. Plain old static HTML/CSS/JS files are actually about as fast as you can get, they're just a pain to deal with if you ever need to make a small change across all of them.

Comment: If I would suggest one thing: Just name everything as `.php` and then you can use simple include statements for basic templating. Eg: `include('footer.php');`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's nothing wrong in not being a programmer, but this is a programming site and your post looks like a generic advice request disguised as technical question, what makes it a discussion more than a question that can be answered according to the site guidelines. 25 files in a folder will not cause a performance problem. Browser will request one page at a time and computers are able to handle folders with thousands of elements. Have you considered using a static site generator?

Comment: I've thought about an SSG; I didn't go look much further into them because I'm trying to use as few different platforms/systems as possible (and though I'm fine with a static site for now, I'd like to try implementing dynamic elements down the line). I didn't mean to sneak in an inappropriate question, but I apologize for the error all the same—anything that I should do about that (i.e. delete the question)? I've at least gotten the answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation on putting files in a directory (In theory there is. but the number is way too high to reach.) So yes, you can create individual html files for your comic book pages and make user navigate trough them.

The con of this is for each page the system need to reload whole page as individual isntead of just the image itself (I assume you saved your pages as jpg or something like that.) So to show a jpg file you make the browser load whole content of page. But no worries; the browsers have really good cache mechanisms. There will be no such thing as waiting too long for loading in your case. (Make sure that you've build your structure correctly)

Better solution for you is actuall creating a small templates and refresing just the image part of your web page instad of whole. You can do that via javascript instead of php. So search a little and create one-page that can include all your comic book pages. When user tries to change page just update the related part of your code. That's all.

Comment: I thank you for this; I'll definitely look into a JS option. My earlier panic is somewhat relieved.